# Install SSL on Windows Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, lets-encrypt

***1. What I want to do:***

I have a domain example.me, and a sub-domain text.example.me which is hosted on my Windows Server. It's running Apache with php 5.6

I want to install and SSL certificate using **Let's Encrypt** and this tool https://github.com/PKISharp/win-acme

***2. The problem:***

It doesn't seem to be working, I get the following error when trying to access https://test.example.me

> This site can’t provide a secure connection

***3. What I have done so far***

I followed every step from:
https://commaster.net/content/how-setup-lets-encrypt-apache-windows

This is the content of my **httpd-ssl.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin me@examole.com
    ServerName text.example.me
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs"

    RewriteEngine On
    # Redirect to the correct domain name
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test.example.me$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://test.example.me/$1 [NE,L,R=301]

    Alias /.well-known D:/xampp/htdocs/.well-known

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/text.example.me-crt.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/test.example.me-key.pem"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "conf/ssl.csr/ca-test.example.me-crt.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

> My 80,443 ports are avaiable, and not being used by Skype, so that's not
>   the issue.

This is the content of my **httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@example.me
    ServerName test.example.me

    RewriteEngine On
    # Redirect to the HTTPS site
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://test.example.me/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
    ErrorLog logs/slog.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: https://github.com/chings228/wacsautomation

i have written an automation for getting key from let's encrypt , see it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) since some years - but without(!) RewriteEngine.

So here is a snipped from my **http-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:/webserver/html/example_html"
  ServerName www.example.com
  Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
  # For the case that you are using ModProxy to forward to a Tomcat, please also add:
  # ProxyPass "/.well-known/" "!"
</VirtualHost>
```

A snipped from my **httpd-ssl.conf**:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot "C:/webserver/html/example_html"
  ServerName www.example.com
  Protocols h2 http/1.1

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
  SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:CAMELLIA128-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:SEED-SHA:DHE-RSA-SEED-SHA:!DSS
  SSLHonorCipherOrder on
  SSLCompression off
  SSLCertificateFile "C:/ProgramData/letsencrypt-win-simple/httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/www.example.com-crt.pem"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:/ProgramData/letsencrypt-win-simple/httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/www.example.com-key.pem"
  SSLCACertificateFile "C:/ProgramData/letsencrypt-win-simple/httpsacme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/ca-www.example.com-crt.pem"

  <IfModule headers_module>
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
  Header always set x-frame-options "SAMEORIGIN"
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
  Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
  #Header always set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'self'"
  </IfModule>

  BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

  #For the case that you use ModProxy to forward to a Tomcat or so
  #ProxyPass "/.well-known/" "!"

  EnableSendfile off
  EnableMMAP off 
</VirtualHost>
```

Also please keep in mind that when you want to use multiple hostnames, then you need a wildcard certificate - otherwise it's simple with Let's Encrypt to have one certificate for each host/domian name - but you need one virtual host section for each host/domain name you are using.

Last but not least my personal opinion is thet ModRewrite should not be used when there is no need, because it is complicate and not really understood by most people.

Comment: After all this time I even forgot about this question, we don't use Windows anymore. But you answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

**How to add SSL certificate from Certbot in Windows Apache**

1. Go to **Certbot’s official website**: Certbot Instructions | Certbot (eff.org)
2. **Download** the latest version of the Certbot installer for Windows at
   https://dl.eff.org/certbot-beta-installer-win_amd64.exe.
3. **Install** it in your C drive.
4. Run > Command Prompt > Run as administrator
5. C:\Users\Administrator>certbot --help
6. C:\Users\Administrator>certbot certonly --webroot
7. Enter your email address > Y > Y
8. Enter your domain/subdomain name: abc.com / abc.xyz.com
9. Go to : C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra
10. Open: httpd-vhosts.conf
11. **Edit**:

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\aeapp
ServerName callum.aeapp.uk
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "C:\Certbot\live\abc.com\fullchain.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\Certbot\live\abc.com\privkey.pem"

12. **Add port 443** in firewall settings (if you have already added then **skip** this step)

- Search > Type: Firewall and open Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security on Local Computer
- Go to:  Inbound rules > New Rule > Select “Port” > Specific Local Ports : Type “443” > Allow the connection > Tick all 3 options > Add name “ ex: abc ssl” > Finish.

13. **Restart** Xampp

**Check your website/webapp; if it's locked, you've added an SSL certificate successfully.**